# How do I transfer source files to Dask workers?

Tags: python, dask

On my dask jupyter node I have the following file layout:

```
main/
  src/
    subfolder/
      file1.py
      file2.py
      file3.py
  main.py
```

The code in `main.py` roughly looks like this:

```
# main.py

from distributed import Client
from src.subfolder.file1 import important_function
# ...

cluster_address = os.environ.get('CLUSTER_ADDRESS', 'dask-scheduler:8786')
client = Client(cluster_address)

arg1, arg2 = ...
future = client.submit(important_function, arg1, arg2)
result = future.result()
```

Actually the story is more complicated since I create the dask workers from a template. But nevertheless, I think this illustrates the problem. When I run this code I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "main.py", line 151, in ...
    result = future.result()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 222, in result
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py", line 59, in loads
    return pickle.loads(x)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

What I tried: I copied all the source folders to the worker, when I spawn the worker. All the source files land in `/build` on the worker. So the entire content of `main` in the example above is actually in directory `/build` on the worker. I guess I need to somehow tell the worker, that the function(s) it receives should be executed in `/build` as their working directory. Is this the way to go? Does anybody have any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Inside `important_function()` I have to append to the sys path like so:

```
def important_function(arg1, arg2):

    sys.path.append("/build")
    # more import statements here
```